# visa stamps on my passport

Tags: visas, australia, work

I'm on a working holiday visa here in Australia and I'm trying to apply for my white card so I can get a construction job while I'm here. But in the course they ask for a picture of my passport and of the visa in it, but when I entered the country I never got one.

Should I just go back and ask for one? Or what should I do?

Comment: Since 2015 Australia does not issue visa stickers at all; all visas are just electronic records. Perhaps you're looking a a form that has not been updated to reflect that fact?

Comment: @HenningMakholm do you know of an official source that mentions the 2015 change in practice, and could you post an answer with it?  It could be useful for someone trying to prove authorized presence in Australia to someone who is unfamiliar with the Australian immigration system.  Roman, you might have to show them a printout of your e-visa, or the admission stamp in your passport (if there is one; some countries have stopped stamping).

Comment: @phoog: unfortunately I'm just regurgitating claims from Wikipedia here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm well maybe someone who is motivated to get some rep will be able to look it up.  I'm sure I've seen something official in the past, but at the moment I don't have time to look for it again.

Comment: Employers already should be aware of this; Home Affairs provides a [web site](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/already-have-a-visa/check-visa-details-and-conditions) that they can use to verify people's visas.

Comment: @phoog The law authorising visa labels was [repealed in 2016](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2016A00034). [VEVO](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/already-have-a-visa/check-visa-details-and-conditions/check-conditions-online) is the only valid way for an employer to check a prospective non-citizen employee's visa status.